# server.tomcat.relaxed-query-chars=[,] seems to allow [ and ] for my whole site, is there a way to do this for a specific api resource?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I am forwarding on some API requests to a service that has a php backend. Thus I need to be able to accept [ and ] on one of my rest resources.  Tomcat has a way to do this for your whole service: server.tomcat.relaxed-query-chars=[,].  For security reasons I only want to allow these on 1 specific api resource instead of on the whole service.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've observed, the Tomcat configuration option applies to the whole server. If you want to do something that's specific to a particular REST resource, you could implement your own `Filter` that checks the characters in the query string for all URLs other than that of the REST resource where you want the check to be more relaxed.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up leaving server.tomcat.relaxed-query-chars=[,].  I then created a RequestBodyAdviceAdapter ControllerAdvice.  If it is not my specific resource, I added logic to validate that it will throw `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986` for [ and ] still for all other resources.

```
@ControllerAdvice
MyControllerAdvice extends org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestBodyAdviceAdapter{

    @Override
    public Object supports(){
      my logic here
    }

    @Override
    public HttpInputMessage beforeBodyRead(){
      my other logic here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it that is specific to url

```
server.tomcat.relaxed-path-chars=[,]
```